# Add dynamicly HTML elements to div without keeping connection b/w them using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

For now I have three functions and two buttons that add elements to a HTML div tag:

```
<style>
#draggable { width: 600px; height: 800px; padding: 0.5em;}
#EditorArea { width: 600px; height: 800px; padding: 0.5em; border: 1px solid black}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
}); 


function MinMax() {
 $("#draggable").append("<table border= 1px><tr><td>Element</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></tr><tr><td>Marked as</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Min</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Max</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Преди ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>След ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time before</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time after</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></table>");
};

function ShowDate() {
 $("#draggable").append("<p class='dateTime' style='width:120px; border: 2px solid black'>DateTime</p>");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="MinMax()">MinMax</button>
<button type="button" onclick="ShowDate()">DateTime</button>
<div id="EditorArea">
<div id="draggable"></div>
</div>
```

Now the default behavior is that every time I add new element it's connected to the previous and so on thus when I move one element I move all added elements. What I want is to be able to move each element freely from the others.

Comment: it is becoz you are adding to the div which is draggable that mean element parent div is draggable not the element itself

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/LKd8S/1/)

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).children().draggable();
         $('#MinMax').click(function(){
              $("#draggable").append("<table border= 1px><tr><td>Element</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></tr><tr><td>Marked as</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Min</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Max</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Преди ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>След ремонт</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time before</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td><tr><td>Time after</td><td><input type='textbox'/></td></table>");
             $( "#draggable" ).children().draggable();
         });
          $('#ShowDate').click(function(){
               $("#draggable").append("<p class='dateTime' style='width:120px; border: 2px solid black'>DateTime</p>");
              $( "#draggable" ).children().draggable();
          });
    });
```